# Using one table instead of two

Tags: mysql, sql, select

I have a problem to display some information. My teacher asked me to change my DB, and it has a big impact on my app.

I have a table in MySql, with columns "user_id", "lastname", and "recruiter_id". The recruiter_id corresponds to the user_id of the recruiter.
For example:

```
user_id  lastname  recruiter_id
1        DO        NULL
2        SMITH     1
3        ROBERT    1
```

In MySql, I would like to show the name of the person who is the recruiter. 
For example, for user_id = 3 I would like to show the name "DO", because the recruiter_id of "robert" is 1, and 1 corresponds to the user_id of "DO".

Before my teacher asked me this, I had 2 different tables, and it was much easier. Now I don't know how to proceed. How do I accomplish this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This calls for a [self-join](http://www.mysqltutorial.org/mysql-self-join/):

```
SELECT    a.lastname AS name, b.last_name as recuirter_name
FROM      users a
LEFT JOIN users b ON a.recruiter_id = b.user_id
```

Comment: Please don't teach newbies to alias table to single-letter names. That is a really bad practice.

Comment: What do you suggest @tereško ?

Comment: @saga `FROM users AS candidates LEFT JOIN users AS recruiters` .. or something like it, then, if you have to later revisit that SQL code, you don't have to look for what each alias means. And when you start getting to joins with 5+ tables, there is no way to remember which letter of alphabet was aliased to what table, You end up looking up the meaning of that letter multiple times.

Comment: Thank you guys it's ok know. I only knew left join for other table. Thx !! ;)

Answer (score 1):

You can easily do this using a left self join:

```
select u.*,
    r.lastname as recruiter_name
from your_table u
left join your_table r on u.recruiter_id = r.user_id;
```

Comment: Please don't teach newbies to alias table to single-letter names. That is a really bad practice.

Comment: @tereško - Well it depends. I'd prefer a smaller alias if it can be meaningful. In this case, u - user, r - recruiter.

Comment: The short reason: it doesn't scale. And you always have to strive to make code more readable, since you tend to read and edit old code a lot more than write new one.

Comment: Thank you guys it's ok know. I only knew left join for other table. Thx !! ;)